# PHPStormでFuelPHPのtasksの処理をデバッグしたいのですが、どうやれば良いでしょうか。

Tags: php, fuelphp, phpstorm

FuelPHPのtasksでPHPStormのデバッガを起動したいです。

```
php oil r [タスク名]
```

↑のように実行して、デバッガで補足してステップ実行などが出来ればと思うのですが、
やり方をご存知の方がいましたら教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpstormで試してみました。phpstorm 10.0.3なら、以下のようにするとローカルマシンのインタプリタでブレイクポイントを指定しての実行などができるようです。もっと賢い設定方法もあるかもしれません。

1. phpstorm用に設定したインタプリタのphp.iniでxdebugを読み込むようにする
2. メニューのRun > Edit Configurations... を開く
3. Fileにoilのパスを指定
4. Argumentsにr [デバッグしたいタスク名]（:起動メソッド名 ※run以外のメソッドで起動する場合のみ必要）
5. わかりやすいよう、Nameにデバッグしたいタスクのファイル名なり＋起動メソッド名なりを入れておく
6. OKで設定を保存
7. デバッグしたいタスクのファイルを開き、止めたい行の左側を左クリックしてブレイクポイント設定
8. 画面右上の設定選択画面で、先ほど保存したNameの設定を選択
9. SHIFT+F9などで、選択中の設定でデバッグ実行

やりたいのがリモートデバッグの場合、サーバ側でPHPを実行した際にphpstormの（ローカルマシン側の）xdebugへDBGPで接続しにくるようサーバ側で設定を行い、またphpstorm側でもそれを待ち受けるよう設定を行う必要があります。
以下が参考になるかと思います。
http://www.1x1.jp/blog/2014/08/how-to-setup-php-remote-debug-with-vagrant-vm.html